# almost surely convergence of poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I'm having trouble with this question, would love to get help!

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a series of variables where $X_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda n)$.
> Show that if $X_n\to 0$ almost surely,  then $\lambda n \to  0$.

Thank you:)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I used the fact that it means it converges in probability so: P(|xn|>E) -> 0 
but I'm not sure why that means that P (xn=0) -> 1

Comment: please ensure you add context (i.e. your attempts) when you ask questions on this site. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence of R.V converges almost surely then it converges in probability. Thus
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) \to 1.$$
In other words
$$e^{-\lambda_n} \to 1$$
so
$$\lambda_n \to 0.$$

Comment: Please don't answer questions that don't meet the site's standards: [EOQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)